# Different Akka Actor instances receive messages

Tags: scala, akka, guice, spray

I created dependency injection with Guice in Spray project as described in [this](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/activator-akka-scala-guice) tutorial.

My Guice module:

```
class ActorsModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule  with GuiceAkkaActorRefProvider {
override def configure() {
  bind[Actor].annotatedWith(Names.named(GenesActor.name)).to[GenesActor]
  bind[Actor].annotatedWith(Names.named(SearchSegmentsActor.name)).to[SearchSegmentsActor]
  bind[Actor].annotatedWith(Names.named(CollectionsFinderActor.name)).to[CollectionsFinderActor]
  bind[Actor].annotatedWith(Names.named(HttpServiceActor.name)).to[HttpServiceActor]
}

@Provides
@Named(GenesActor.name)
def provideGenesActorRef(@Inject() system: ActorSystem): ActorRef =   provideActorRef(system, GenesActor.name)

@Provides
@Named(SearchSegmentsActor.name)
def provideSearchSegmentsActorRef(@Inject() system: ActorSystem): ActorRef = provideActorRef(system, SearchSegmentsActor.name)

@Provides
@Named(CollectionsFinderActor.name)
def provideCollectionsFinderActorRef(@Inject() system: ActorSystem):   ActorRef = provideActorRef(system, CollectionsFinderActor.name)

}
```

I have http service actor, which gets by injections other actors and forwards messages to those actors:

```
object HttpServiceActor extends NamedActor {
  override final val name: String = "HttpServiceActor"
}

class HttpServiceActor @Inject()(@Named(SearchSegmentsActor.name) searchSegmentsActor: ActorRef,
                             @Named(CollectionsFinderActor.name) collectionsFinderActor: ActorRef,
                             @Named(GenesActor.name) genesActor: ActorRef)
                                extends Actor with SearchHttpService with ActorLogging {

                 def actorRefFactory = context

                 def receive = runRoute(
                      sprayRoute(searchSegmentsActor, collectionsFinderActor, genesActor) ~
                         staticRoute)

       }
```

and I need to send periodically messages to one of this injected actors, so my main method looks like:

```
val injector = Guice.createInjector(
  new ConfigModule(),
  new AkkaModule(),
  new DaoModule(),
  new ActorsModule()
)

implicit val system = injector.getInstance(classOf[ActorSystem])

val service = system.actorOf(GuiceAkkaExtension(system).props(HttpServiceActor.name))
val collectionsActor = system.actorOf(GuiceAkkaExtension(system).props(CollectionsFinderActor.name))
system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 1 minutes, collectionsActor, new RefreshCollections())

IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(service, system.settings.config.getString("app.interface"), system.settings.config.getInt("app.port"))
```

Actually I see that I have 2 instances of CollectionsFinderActor - one receives scheduled messages every 1 minute and the second receives messages forwarded by HttpServiceActor

Of course this is not what I expect - I want that the same instance of  CollectionsFinderActor will receive both messages.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding @Singleton annotation to provideGenesActorRef method

```
@Provides
@Named(GenesActor.name)
def provideGenesActorRef(@Inject() system: ActorSystem): ActorRef =   provideActorRef(system, GenesActor.name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick guess. If I remember, guice by default creates a new instance of the service every time you ask for it. At least, it doesn't promise to reuse them.

You will have to inject actor system, and lookup the actor ref every time you need it instead. Slight improvement could be adding a service, that would wrap actor system and communication with actors. Then inject this new service instead of actors etc.

That's the way described by authors of [framework](http://letitcrash.com/post/55958814293/akka-dependency-injection):

Comment: They write that you should not make actors singletons to allow Akka recreate them

Comment: You can have a look at Play docs. They described how to integrate akka guice and play, maybe there you will find some idea to reuse in your project https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka

Comment: Unfortunately all this does not help - I get different actor instances

Comment: When you need to send a message to some actor from different points, you don't have to inject them. If that is the part of app outside the actors, then inject into it the actor system itself, and lookup the destination actor by name/path. @PavelBernshtam

Comment: I send messages from the actor from another actor. I tried both approached - inject actor ref to the first actor or inject ActorSystem and get reference to the actor ref each time. In both situations I different Actor instances receive each message

Comment: Or, more correctly - I get new Actor instance for each time I get new ActorRef from ActorSystem. Using the same actor ref provides me the same actor instance